# secure file exchange

Tags: web-applications, security

I would like to set up a web application on my company's Linux box for enabling secure file exchange with our customers. I'm looking for an open source application, preferably with a large user base, that supports these features:

- works over HTTPS (so SFTP or other similar solutions are out of the question)
- allows users to upload files using credentials that we provide them with in advance
- the files thus uploaded should only be visible when using the same account (or an admin account)
- allows an admin to upload files into a user account for the user to download (this doesn't necessarily have to happen via the webapp)
- (optional) it should provide email notification when new files are uploaded by users
- (optional) it should ensure automatic cleanup of the uploaded files, preferably after a period of time that the uploader can set

I've spent some time searching for such an application both on Google and stack overflow, but I haven't found anything compelling yet. Maybe someone here knows about such a thing and can help me with a pointer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A while ago, I had to develop my own applications to do that. Nowadays, I would recommend using a paid service to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be F*EX, see http://fex.rus.uni-stuttgart.de/

Comment: Sounds brilliant. I would even say "exactly what I asked for", which is why I set this as the "accepted answer" to my question. There's a catch, though, which I failed to specify exactly. I need it to runnable within Apache, since I can't take Apache down and I can't move it to another port.

Comment: And, as you mention in the FAQ, this is not possible. I see you mention two other projects there, I will have a look, maybe I find what I need there. In either case, thanks for writing and pointing me to F*EX.

Comment: For more questions, contact me directly by e-mail: framstag@rus.uni-stuttgart.de

Answer (score 1):

How about [WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/)?  This is what [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) uses to sync files over HTTPS.  Here's a [list of open source WebDAV projects](http://www.webdav.org/projects/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've started experimenting with WebDAV yesterday and it got me some steps ahead. It's not quite as plug-and-play as I would have wished, but I might be able to use it. Still hoping for a slightly more friendly web application.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps put together something cheaply with Bugzilla, maybe with a careful reskinning. Set it up so that client-created tickets are private, visible only to themselves and to the admin group. To send a file to a client you would create a new ticket only visible to the correct group and attach the file to it. You get email interfacing pretty much for free, and you might well find you can auto-expire old "tickets".